# Cell of Collection does not let to be unchecked after making it selected

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview

I've been stuggling for a while with saving which cell was marked and which not, the problem was not that hard. After few tries it is all about saving `indePath` somewhere and after return to the view with collection we are able to do some stuffs on the `array` of the choosen `indexPaths` inside `willDisplay` of the `collectionView` method. Basically that how it looks :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        switch collectionView {
        case myCollection:
            var count: Int = 0
            if !SessionMenager.Instance.indexPaths.isEmpty {
                for index in SessionMenager.Instance.indexPaths {
                    if index == indexPath {
                        print(SessionMenager.Instance.indexPaths.count)
                        myCollection.selectItem(at: SessionMenager.Instance.indexPaths[count], animated: true, scrollPosition: .bottom)
                        var image = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
                        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                            image.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
                            image = image.drawRingForCircle(imageView: image, color: .white)
                        })
                        cell.isSelected = true
                        count += 1
                    }
                }
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

Which works perfect but only for a one way. Now I am not able to deselect any of selected cells except the first selected before going to another `view` - why is that ? Does any one could help me ?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath {

switch collectionView {

case xxx:
         break
case yyy: 
         break
        case myCollection:
            let image = myCollection.cellForItem(at: indexPath)?.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                image.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
                image.layer.sublayers?.removeLast()
            })

            for (key, _) in tmpDict {
                if key == image {
                    if let index = self.choosenData.index(of: tmpDict[key]! ) {
                        self.choosenData.remove(at: index)
                        SessionMenager.Instance.indexPaths = SessionMenager.Instance.indexPaths.filter { $0 != indexPath }
                    }
                }
            }
        default:
            break
        }
}
```

Comment: Well, how are you trying to deselect the cells? You only posted the code which does the selecting part.

Comment: @PedroCastilho it does not enter to the method `didDeselectItemAt` for other cells then the first one saved. But hire u are!

Comment: Why the `switch` statement?

Comment: @PedroCastilho I have few collectons. There is no point to paste them there. Sorry for not pointing that!

Comment: You shouldn't use a switch statement for that. Swift class objects compare by reference equality, which can lead to weird behavior. You should implement the `Equatable` protocol instead.

Comment: @PedroCastilho OK! I will change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER**

I fugure out what must be done to make it works! 
Basically whenever someone will have similar problems I do not recomend `willDisplay cell` method - it will not works in that case well.
While you invoke a `.selectItem` on a collection inside this method, the cell yes it will be selected but.. there is one problem, even while u set these on selected the delegate after u click inside a cell will jump into `didSelectItemAt` instead of `didDeselectItemAt` so to uncheck the cell you need click twice which is not good.

The second thing we might add to `willDisplay cell` `.isSelected = true` but after that we solved `~50%` of our problem becouse we can not deselect them any more, the delegate does not react any more for other selected cells instead of first selected.

I ask my self, what if I do the same stuff after everything is loaded ? Then I've tryid it - it works!

For that I used `viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)`.

The working example looks like :

```
if !SessionMenager.Instance.indexPaths.isEmpty {
            for index in SessionMenager.Instance.colorsIndexPaths {
                let cell = myCollection.cellForItem(at: index)!
                myCollection.selectItem(at: index, animated: true, scrollPosition: .bottom)
                var something = cell.viewWithTag(**YOUR TAG**) as! SMTH

                // And the body what would you like to do with `something`, ex. increase scale of item, change a background, tint color etc.

                })
            }
        }
```

Hope it will helps anyone who needs that! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

How about changing your `collectionView(_:willDisplay:forItemAt:)` method to this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    var count: Int = 0
    for index in SessionMenager.Instance.indexPaths {
        if index == indexPath {
            myCollection.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .bottom)
            var image = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                image.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
                image = image.drawRingForCircle(imageView: image, color: .white)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

It might not solve your issue, but it will definitely be simpler to debug. Also, you don't need to set `isSelected` on your cell directly. `UICollectionView.selectItem` does that already.

You should also check if you're getting all the correct `IndexPath`s, and call `UICollectionView.reloadData` on your collection view after you're done loading data.

Comment: `isSelected` is needed becouse somehow if you does not do that the cells thinks it is not selected yet, even if i have changed the view etc. it does need to be clicked twice to get deselected, so at the first time it goes to selected and then second time to deselected :D werid behavior - alrady debugged. The paths are also correct. I've made an algorythm to keep them well.

Comment: It shouldn't be needed. From Apple's docs: ["You typically do not set the value of this property directly. Changing the value of this property programmatically does not change the appearance of the cell. The preferred way to select the cell and highlight it is to use the selection methods of the collection view object."](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewcell/1620130-isselected)

Comment: I agree with you, but somehow does not work like they say. While i put selected item it should goes after selection on the selected item for the first step to `didSelectItemAt` but to the `didDeselectItemAt`